# Trying to save a users input to a xml file?

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I have made a itty bitty website just to store all the links I need to remember. It works great but I want a way for a user to save all of the links they have already entered so they don't lose all of them when the browser tab is closed.

I believe the best way to achieve this would be with xml, but I am definitely open to any and all ideas.

```
<script>
  function GetLinks() {
    var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
    var y = document.createElement("INPUT");
    y.setAttribute("type", "text");
    y.setAttribute("value", "Name");
    document.body.appendChild(y);
    x.setAttribute("type", "url");
    x.setAttribute("value", "URL");
    document.body.appendChild(x);
    var z = document.createElement("HR")
    document.body.appendChild(z);
 }
```

I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: quick question are you saving data from HTML form to XML ?

Answer (score 0):

```
   <form action="" method="post">
        <p>
           <label for="firstname">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname">

            <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname">


        <button type="button" onclick="download(this.form)" id="submitButton">Download</button>

</form>
```

JS

```
function downloadData(contentType,data,filename){

   var link=document.createElement("A");
   link.setAttribute("href",encodeURI("data:"+contentType+","+data));
   link.setAttribute("style","display:none");
   link.setAttribute("download",filename);
   document.body.appendChild(link); //needed for firefox
   console.log(link.outerHTML);
   link.click();
   setTimeout(function(){
    document.body.removeChild(link);
   },1000);
}

function fromToXml(form){
    var xmldata=['<?xml version="1.0"?>'];
      xmldata.push("<form>");
    var inputs=form.elements;
    for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){
        var el=document.createElement("ELEMENT");
      if (inputs[i].name){
        el.setAttribute("name",inputs[i].name);
        el.setAttribute("value",inputs[i].value);
        xmldata.push(el.outerHTML);
      }

    }
    xmldata.push("</form>");
    return xmldata.join("\n");
}


function download(frm){

    var data=fromToXml(frm);
  console.log(data);

  downloadData("text/xml",data,"export.xml");
}
```

also, I am referencing the demo URL enter the values and then press download it will show you the values https://jsfiddle.net/0he5ta8j/ let me know if you were looking this

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much!

Comment: @jonathan can you please up-vote the answer so it will help others as well accept it as answer if you think it is what you asked Thanks